Pass `configurable-env` to cargo custom subcommand
I have a script named cargo-custom located in my $PATH. The script looks like this:
#!/usr/bin/bash
echo "Using DATA_PATH: $DATA_PATH"
echo "Cargo target dir: $CARGO_TARGET_DIR"
echo "$@"

The content of my .cargo/config.toml file is as follows:
[env]
DATA_PATH = { value = "data/", relative = true }

I expected the $DATA_PATH environment variable to be set when running the script, but when I execute the following command:
cargo custom -- args

The output is:
Using DATA_PATH: 
Cargo target dir: 
custom -- args

Is it possible to pass configurable environment variables from the Cargo configuration to my script? If so, how can I achieve this?

Looks like an open issue
